# Using a class as a struct in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to make the equivalent of this `C++` code in `Java`:

```
struct element {
  int x;
  int y;
};
int main()
{   
   element element1;
   element1.x=2;
   element1.y=4;
}
```

What I've done so far is this:

```
class element {
   public int x;
   public int y;        
}
public class Class1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        element KK;
        KK.x=1;
        KK.y=2;
    }
}
```

I will have to create multiple element Objects and store different values in them. These are the errors I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>           The local variable KK may not have been initialized
>           The local variable KK may not have been initialized

How can I properly do this?

Comment: You have to create the object `element  KK = new element()`

Answer (score 5):

Unlike in C++, you always explicitly create objects in Java via `new`. So this:

```
element KK;
```

just declares the variable, it doesn't initialize it, and it doesn't create an object. You do:

```
element KK = new element();
```

or if you prefer (and if you're using Java 10 or higher):

```
var KK = new element();
```